# Sound disappears during crossfade with HTML5 audio players on iOS Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Experiencing very strange behaviour with html5 audio players on ios safari and chrome (probably with others).

I have two players crossfading one to another. Crossfade made with WebAudio api with gain nodes and `linearRampToValueAtTime`. And it works good every odd number. First ( 1 -> 2) crossfade is perfect and smooth. On second crossfade (2 -> 1) when I'm starting playback of first player sound disappears. `timeupdate` events continued to be emitted, gain value is 0.5, player volume is 1, `currentTime` of contexts are valid, before crossfade `setValueAtTime` is set for both. But no sound. Next crossfade perfect. Next fails. Even while playback is active when I execute in console `player1.src = "url"; player1.play()` player2 continue playback but without sound. Another notice that it happens only when I change src. When src is not changed it crossfades 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 excellent. After src change im running `load()` and seek to 0. And still it happens every every even time

```
    nextPlayer.src = "http://example.com/1.mp3";
    nextPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    nextPlayer.load();
    nextPlayer.play().then(() => {
        this.__crossFade();
    });
```

What am I missing? What can it cause?